# Java copy speed using NIO Files.copy()

Tags: java, windows

When using **Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)** is there a way to tell the speed at which the file is being copied? I was thinking that I would check the size of the target each second and do the math new - old size, but this function is allocating the whole size from the start on disk, so this would return no change. I could use **InputStream/OutputStream** and that way I can easily do the math from buffer, but **Files.copy** is faster.

Comment: No there isn't a way to do that using `Files.copy`.

Comment: That is unfortunate, thanks. I'll have to decide then if I should remove the speed, or use a different way, even if it is slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do that using Files.copy.

1. The Files.copy API doesn't provide any way to monitor the transfer.
2. In some cases (e.g. on UNIX / Linux / MacOS) the copying may be done using the `sendfile` syscall.  The copy is performed in kernel space so there is no buffer that could be monitored<sup>1</sup>.  This is so-called "zero copy" I/O.

The use of the `sendfile` syscall is a large part of what makes the `Files.copy` a lot faster than using `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and buffers.  As they say ... you can't have your cake and eat it.

---

<sup>1 ... even if you were willing and able to use reflection to break class abstraction, etc.</sup>